# is there is anyway for making CSS Grid only for columns without rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying since 3 days until now and searching for a way to make the elements inside the grid has a free height, the reason why I am asking this is: the height of the elements are on the same row will automatically get the same height "stretch", I tried to remove this "stretch" by changing it to "start" so: inside the class of the grid I did the following :

```
.grid{
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-gap: 10px;
align-items: start; /*default stretch*/
}
```

now what happened is: **the elements (the blocks "divs")** whose inside the grid, between the columns are pushed upside of the row, so now they are stacking on the top of 'their' rows.

okay the problem now is:
 I want to make **the elements (the blocks "divs")**
NOT on the Same row I want to make something like Nesting between rows and not columns BUT automatically not manually.

see this photo for more explain:
it's being like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIVMA.png)

I want it like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKWIh.png)

if we used the align-items: start ; then there will be a space between the element in the first row and in the element on the second row.
(see the photos for explain)

so i think and found that it's impossible to do this  except if we made a grid system with only columns but without rows.

eg: I want to create a grid system like this: from materializecss themes:
https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/demo

and not by using grid template areas or those commands.
very hard and impossible? solution?

I want the user to manually create there own cards , and the grid system automatically to responsive it.

Comment: You can have nested grids so first grid is for your columns and each column is a grid for it's internal items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for what's called a “masonry” layout, named for the JS library that handles it. This isn't possible with CSS alone if your items are in a flat hierarchy (i.e. they're all siblings, no containers for the columns).

[Here's a link to the Masonry library](https://masonry.desandro.com/) for reference.

If you wanted to handle this entirely in HTML/CSS, you could do so by creating the three columns and adding your children to those columns:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.col {}

.el {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el" style="height: 110px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 50px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 70px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 90px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el" style="height: 50px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 70px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="el" style="height: 70px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="el" style="height: 50px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```